# JavaScript: I need checkbox input to be checked while clicked on the <p> Tag

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, checkbox, ejs

I want to make the checkbox inout be checked as per the below snapshot code so when I click of any of the Todo Item (Buy Lunch,....etc.) the checkbox input be checked and after writing below code it is only applied on the first element only whatever I clicked any paragraph (Todo item).

```
// Clicking Todo Item to fire checked Input 
 
let paragraphs =document.querySelectorAll('p');
let checkBoxInput = document.getElementById('checkedInput');
 


  for(var i=0; i < paragraphs.length; i++){
    paragraphs[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
          this.style.color = "#2a6850";
          checkBoxInput.checked = true;
      }, false);
  }
```

[image]

So how to click each todo list item not to click on checkbox itself and it being fired and make this like image not

```
EJS File:

<div class="item">
    <input type="checkbox" name="" id="checkedInput">
    <p>
        <%= newItem %>
    </p>
</div>
```

```
CSS

input:checked + p {
    text-decoration: line-through;
    text-decoration-color: #2da883;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however I am not using google translate at all here!!

Comment: You're selecting first checkbox using `let checkBoxInput = document.getElementById('checkedInput');` If you want checkbox for each entry, use querySelectorAll instead of id

Comment: Thanks Sagar I don't know how I missed this but what am confused now is to trigger the only related checkbox as the below code once I clicked on buy lunch it is triggered all the checkboxes!

Comment: ```
let paragraphs =document.querySelectorAll('p');
let checkBoxInput = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');

  for(var i=0; i < paragraphs.length; i++){
    paragraphs[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
        //   alert('hello');
          this.style.color = "#2a6850";

                checkBoxInput[i].checked = true;

      }, false);
  }

```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had Solved it Used the below code I had created ... Thanks all :)

```
let paragraphs =document.querySelectorAll('p'); 
let checkBoxInput = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
        
          for(var i=0; i < paragraphs.length; i++){
            paragraphs[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
           
                this.style.color = "rgb(228 233 253)";
                this.style.borderRadius = "10%";
                this.style.backgroundColor = "#0c0b07";
                this.previousElementSibling.checked = true;
        
              }, false);
             }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use `label` instead of `p`, so that browser does the work for you.

Your EJS file would look like that:

```
<div class="item">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkedInput" id="checkedInput">
    <label for="checkedInput">
        <%= newItem %>
    </label>
</div>
```

But you have to make sure that after your app is rendered each checkbox has a unique id.